# Use env variable in href

Tags: html, xhtml

I have following .xhtml file

```
<h:body>
        You have been logged out. Click here <a href="http://mytestserver.com/MyApp/HomePage.jsf">Login</a>   to logon again.  
</h:body>
```

Now http://mytestserver.com is different in test and production. So i am using env variable
MY_URL=http://mytestserver.com/MyApp/HomePage.jsf
MY_URL=http://myprodserver.com/MyApp/HomePage.jsf

How do i reference MY_URL heremin href

Comment: Instead of relying on some variable can't you just use a relative url `/MyApp/HomePage.jsf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggested, just use relative paths:

```
<h:body>
    You have been logged out. Click here <a href="/MyApp/HomePage.jsf">Login</a>   to logon again.  
</h:body>
```

Problem solved, and you can host this on any server you like, no variable needed.